# Drupal-7 - Lists and Custom Content Types

Tags: 7

I've just started with Drupal-7 coming from Drupal-5 that I last used a few years back and made a few customisations too. It seems to be Drupal-5 was much easier for modification, though Im starting to work out where all the data is saved processing through all the examples.

What isn't clear is when is a node not a node. For example, there are various support lists that I would like in my customisations, for example "salutation" (mr, mrs, miss, dr, revd etc) that should be user maintainable and stored in a database. It seems a bit overkill to create a separate content type and node just for this.

The current project Im working on is for Events, but I need to sub-categorise those Events twice by Event Type and Sub-Event-Type. Both of these should be user maintainable and therefore database driven. I can put them in a Content Type/Node but it does seem overkill.

I can't figure out if there's a programmatical way to insert, alter, delete (like the old days) into their own tables and then reference them in the Event node I will create generating a dynamic list.

There are lots of information out there about using Values, Taxonomy and Views etc. Seems everybody shys away from programming now and there's no examples anymore!

Any thoughts where to start? It seemed much easier finding the information before.

Answer (score 1):

[Organizing content with taxonomy](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy) (category) is a very powerful tool of Drupal.

> What isn't clear is when is a node not a node. For example, there are
>   various support lists that I would like in my customisations, for
>   example "salutation" (mr, mrs, miss, dr, revd etc) that should be user
>   maintainable and stored in a database. It seems a bit overkill to
>   create a separate content type and node just for this.

According to this, you can manage "**salutation**" with taxonomy . The"**salutation**" is a **vocabulary** and "mr, mrs, miss, dr, revd" are **terms** of the vocabulary. They will be stored in the taxonomy table and the path **admin/structure/taxonomy/your_vocabulary** will be user maintainable list page.

You can create a custom field ( **term reference** ) to your vocabulary ( "**salutation**" in this case ) for your content type.
They can be chosen from a list when user creates a node.

Same concept for your Event Type and Sub-Event Type.
The [Taxonomy Manager](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) module may help you.

Comment: That looks absolutely perfect. Thank you. Works pretty well.